# Converting JPQL query to Criteria Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

In order to learn JPA I'm trying to explore various ways to execute queries. I have native SQL and JPQL queries which work as expected. Now I'm trying to achieve the same by Criteria Query approach.
My entities:

```
@Entity
public class GiftCertificate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Column(precision = 10, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal price;

    private Short duration;

    private LocalDateTime createDate;

    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDate;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "gift_certificate_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gift_certificate_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(tags);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private GiftCertificate giftCertificate;

    private LocalDateTime orderDate;

    private BigDecimal orderCost;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tag", schema = "public")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    //@Basic(optional = false)
    //@NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String userName;

}
```

The task is to get the most widely used tag of a user with the highest cost of all orders

Working SQL:

```
SELECT *
        FROM   tag
               JOIN (SELECT tag_id,
                            Count (gift_certificate_tag.gift_certificate_id) AS
                            cert_count
                     FROM   gift_certificate_tag
                            JOIN orders
                              ON gift_certificate_tag.gift_certificate_id =
                                 orders.gift_certificate_id
                            JOIN (SELECT user_id,
                                         Sum (order_cost) AS all_orders_cost
                                  FROM   orders
                                  GROUP  BY user_id
                                  ORDER  BY all_orders_cost DESC
                                  LIMIT  1) AS orders_sum
                              ON orders_sum.user_id = orders.user_id
                     GROUP  BY tag_id
                     ORDER  BY cert_count DESC
                     LIMIT  1) AS result
                 ON result.tag_id = tag.id
```

Working JPQL:

```
SELECT new Tag(t.id, t.name)
                FROM GiftCertificate gc
                JOIN gc.tags t
                JOIN Order o ON o.giftCertificate = gc
                JOIN o.user u
                WHERE u = (
                      SELECT ou
                      FROM Order o2
                      JOIN o2.user ou
                      GROUP BY ou
                      HAVING SUM(o2.orderCost) = (
                            SELECT MAX(totalOrderCost)
                            FROM (
                                  SELECT SUM(o3.orderCost) AS totalOrderCost
                                  FROM Order o3
                                  GROUP BY o3.user
                            ) subquery
                      )
                )
                GROUP BY t.id, t.name
                ORDER BY COUNT(gc) DESC
```

Not working Criteria Query:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Tag> cq = cb.createQuery(Tag.class);
        Root<Order> order = cq.from(Order.class);
        Join<Order, GiftCertificate> giftCertificate = order.join("giftCertificate");
        Join<GiftCertificate, Tag> tag = giftCertificate.join("tags");
        Join<Order, User> user = order.join("user");

        //sub-query to find user's orders sums
        Subquery<BigDecimal> querySumOfOrders = cq.subquery(BigDecimal.class);
        Root<Order> subOrderSumOfOrders = querySumOfOrders.from(Order.class);
        Join<Order, User> subUserSumOfOrders = subOrderSumOfOrders.join("user");
        querySumOfOrders.select(cb.sum(subOrderSumOfOrders.get("orderCost")))
                        .groupBy(subUserSumOfOrders);

        //sub-query to find max cost of the user's orders sum
        Subquery<BigDecimal> queryMaxOrdersSum = cq.subquery(BigDecimal.class);
        queryMaxOrdersSum.from(Order.class);
        queryMaxOrdersSum.select(cb.max(querySumOfOrders));

        //sub-query to find user with most cost of all orders
        Subquery<User> queryMostSpentUser = cq.subquery(User.class);
        Root<Order> subOrderMostSpentUser = queryMostSpentUser.from(Order.class);
        Join<Order, User> subUserMostSpentUser = subOrderMostSpentUser.join("user");
        queryMostSpentUser.select(subUserMostSpentUser)
                          .having(cb.equal(cb.sum(subOrderMostSpentUser.get("orderCost")), cb.max(queryMaxOrdersSum)))
                          .groupBy(subUserMostSpentUser);
        //main query
        cq.select(tag)
          .where(cb.equal(user, queryMostSpentUser))
          .orderBy(cb.desc(cb.count(giftCertificate)))
          .groupBy(tag);
        List<Tag> tagList = entityManager.createQuery(cq)
                                         .setMaxResults(1)
                                         .getResultList();
```

The SQL generated by Hibernate from criteria query:

```
select
        t1_1.id,
        t1_1.name 
    from
        public.orders o1_0 
    join
        public.gift_certificate g1_0 
            on g1_0.id=o1_0.gift_certificate_id 
    join
        (public.gift_certificate_tag t1_0 
    join
        public.tag t1_1 
            on t1_1.id=t1_0.tag_id) 
                on g1_0.id=t1_0.gift_certificate_id 
        join
            public.users u1_0 
                on u1_0.id=o1_0.user_id 
        where
            u1_0.id=(
                select
                    u2_0.id 
                from
                    public.orders o2_0 
                join
                    public.users u2_0 
                        on u2_0.id=o2_0.user_id 
                group by
                    1 
                having
                    sum(o2_0.order_cost)=(
                        select
                            max((select
                                sum(o4_0.order_cost) 
                            from
                                public.orders o4_0 
                            join
                                public.users u3_0 
                                    on u3_0.id=o4_0.user_id 
                            group by
                                o4_0.user_id)) 
                        from
                            public.orders o3_0)
                    ) 
                group by
                    1,
                    2 
                order by
                    count(o1_0.gift_certificate_id) desc fetch first ? rows only
```

The problem is with the following SQL block:

```
                select max((select
                                sum(o4_0.order_cost) 
                            from
                                public.orders o4_0 
                            join
                                public.users u3_0 
                                    on u3_0.id=o4_0.user_id 
                            group by
                                o4_0.user_id))
```

this causes org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

The question is how to make criteria query instead generate SQL same as generated in case of JPQL query:

```
                        select max(subquery1_0.totalOrderCost) 
                        from
                            (select
                                sum(o3_0.order_cost) 
                            from
                                public.orders o3_0 
                            group by
                                o3_0.user_id) subquery1_0(totalOrderCost)
```

Comment: So the root of the problem is not in SQL, but in criteria query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "JPQL" (actually HQL) can only work with Hibernate 6+, because before that, Hibernate did not support subqueries in the from clause. To use that feature from JPA Criteria, you have to use the Hibernate JPA Criteria extensions.

```
    HibernateCriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getCriteriaBuilder();
    JpaCriteriaQuery<Tag> cq = cb.createQuery(Tag.class);
    JpaRoot<Order> order = cq.from(Order.class);
    JpaJoin<Order, GiftCertificate> giftCertificate = order.join("giftCertificate");
    JpaJoin<GiftCertificate, Tag> tag = giftCertificate.join("tags");
    JpaJoin<Order, User> user = order.join("user");

    //sub-query to find user's orders sums
    JpaSubquery<Tuple> querySumOfOrders = cq.subquery(Tuple.class);
    JpaRoot<Order> subOrderSumOfOrders = querySumOfOrders.from(Order.class);
    querySumOfOrders.multiselect(cb.sum(subOrderSumOfOrders.get("orderCost")).alias("theSum"))
                    .groupBy(subOrderSumOfOrders.get("user"));

    //sub-query to find max cost of the user's orders sum
    JpaSubquery<BigDecimal> queryMaxOrdersSum = cq.subquery(BigDecimal.class);
    JpaRoot<Tuple> queryMaxOrders = queryMaxOrdersSum.from(querySumOfOrders);
    queryMaxOrdersSum.select(cb.max(queryMaxOrders.get("theSum")));

    //sub-query to find user with most cost of all orders
    JpaSubquery<User> queryMostSpentUser = cq.subquery(User.class);
    JpaRoot<Order> subOrderMostSpentUser = queryMostSpentUser.from(Order.class);
    JpaJoin<Order, User> subUserMostSpentUser = subOrderMostSpentUser.join("user");
    queryMostSpentUser.select(subUserMostSpentUser)
                      .having(cb.equal(cb.sum(subOrderMostSpentUser.get("orderCost")), cb.max(queryMaxOrdersSum)))
                      .groupBy(subUserMostSpentUser);
    //main query
    cq.select(tag)
      .where(cb.equal(user, queryMostSpentUser))
      .orderBy(cb.desc(cb.count(giftCertificate)))
      .groupBy(tag);
    List<Tag> tagList = entityManager.createQuery(cq)
                                     .setMaxResults(1)
                                     .getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution works with 2 minor corrections: 1) JpaRoot.join(String s) returns Join type, not JpaJoin. 2) as() method replaced with alias(). However originally I was looking for JPA provider independent solution. So I wonder is there any way to get same result without native Hibernate features, even if resulting SQL will be completely different. Or jakarta.persistence limitations are so huge that it makes basically impossible to perform some data extraction in a single criteria query?

Comment: JPA does not support subqueries in the `from` clause and as far as I know, only Hibernate supports this through JPA Criteria. So there is nothing provider independent you can do. It's a Hibernate only feature.