# How to combine series of two criteria queries into single Criteria query with subqueries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have the following JPQL query which I need to convert to criteria query:

```
SELECT new Tag(t.id, t.name)
FROM GiftCertificate gc
JOIN gc.tags t
JOIN Order o ON o.giftCertificate = gc
JOIN o.user u
WHERE u = (
      SELECT ou
      FROM Order o2
      JOIN o2.user ou
      GROUP BY ou
      HAVING SUM(o2.orderCost) = (
            SELECT MAX(totalOrderCost)
            FROM (
                  SELECT SUM(o3.orderCost) AS totalOrderCost
                  FROM Order o3
                  GROUP BY o3.user
            ) subquery
      )
)
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
ORDER BY COUNT(gc) DESC
```

This query gets the most widely used tag of a user with the highest cost of all orders.

The only working solution I come up with is to use two separate criteria queries in series.
First to find user with highest sum of orders:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        
CriteriaQuery<User> userQuery = cb.createQuery(User.class);
Root<Order> userQueryRoot = userQuery.from(Order.class);
Join<Order, User> user = userQueryRoot.join("user");
userQuery.select(user)
         .groupBy(user)
         .orderBy(cb.desc(cb.sum(userQueryRoot.get("orderCost"))));
User mostOrdersCostUser = entityManager.createQuery(userQuery)
                                       .setMaxResults(1)
                                       .getSingleResult();
```

And second to find the most used tag for orders of user found in first query:

```
CriteriaQuery<Tag> tagQuery = cb.createQuery(Tag.class);
        Root<Order> tagQueryroot = tagQuery.from(Order.class);
        Join<Order, GiftCertificate> giftCertificate = tagQueryroot.join("giftCertificate");
        Join<GiftCertificate, Tag> tag = giftCertificate.join("tags");
        tagQuery.select(tag)
                .where(cb.equal(tagQueryroot.get("user"), mostOrdersCostUser))
                .groupBy(tag)
                .orderBy(cb.desc(cb.count(giftCertificate)));
        Tag mostUsedtag = entityManager.createQuery(tagQuery).setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
```

Using two separate queries in series has obvious disadvantages. But due to limitations of Subquery I was unable to compose single Criteria query with subqueries. So I wondering is there a better approach then using series of two separate queries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting JPQL query to Criteria Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75599897/converting-jpql-query-to-criteria-query)

Comment: @ChristianBeikov well, yes in a way of finding working solution, but not exactly in a way of finding JPA provider independent solution.

Comment: JPA does not support subqueries in the `from` clause and as far as I know, only Hibernate supports this through JPA Criteria. So there is nothing provider independent you can do. It's a Hibernate only feature.